# How to convert RedisonListMultimap<String, String> or Collection<Map.Entry<String, String>> to Map<String, List<String>>

Tags: java, redis, collections, type-conversion, redisson

I've got redisson `RListMultimap<String, String>` type, which contains elements in strucure similar to java's `Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>`

https://redisson.org/glossary/java-multimap.html

https://github.com/redisson/redisson/blob/master/redisson/src/main/java/org/redisson/RedissonMultimap.java

Now I want to convert data from redisson type after calling `redissonClient.getListMultimap(key1)`  method to standard Java `Map<String, List<String>>`

After calling `getListMultimap` I'm receiving data structure like Java's `Map<String, List<String>>` but it's a struture called `RListMultimap`

I think the best option to do it is by call `entries()` method on redissonClient's response which returns `Collection<Map.Entry<String, String>>` and then convert this from this type to `Map<String, List<String>>`

Is anyone know to convert between this two data types in Java or know a better way to do it?